# managing options using radio button

Tags: html, radio-button

I am having a number of options that a user can select only one at a time, so I chose to use radio buttons to present them. For some reason I do not know, all the radio button can be selected at the same time. I wish to know what I must do to select on one radio at a time. I use blade template alongside twitter bootstrap 3.0.

Comment: This actually skipped my mind for a short while. I did not give myself  enough time think. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be mutually exclusive the radio inputs must have the same name (for each group of mutually-exclusive inputs):

```
<!-- mutually exclusive group -->
<input type="radio" value="1" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="group1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**you have to create a radiobutton group , and add all your radio buttons to it, like so:**

```
ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

 JRadioButton jRadio1 = new JRadioButton();
 JRadioButton jRadio2 = new JRadioButton();
 JRadioButton jRadio3 = new JRadioButton();

  jRadio1 .setSelected(true);   // Default Selection
  jRadio1 .setText("xxx");  // RadioButton Text
  jRadio2 .setText("yyy");  // RadioButton Text
  jRadio3 .setText("zzz");  // RadioButton Text

 radioButtonGroup.add(jRadio1);
 radioButtonGroup.add(jRadio2);
 radioButtonGroup.add(jRadio3);
```

that should do the trick ;)